# What statistical analysis should we use for this aviation study?

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data

I am helping a friend with an aviation research study. We have two categorical variables for our IV (Group 1 consists of low-cost airlines, Group 2 consist of legacy carriers), our dependent variable is continuous (Average Arrival Delay in minutes). For example, in a span of 5 years, airline X in group 1 might have an average arrival delay of 5 minutes for all flights, and airline Y in group 2 might have an average delay of 3 minutes for all flights. Essentially, we are trying to see if there is a difference in average delays (in minutes) between group 1 or 2. The only data we have access to for the DV is the average arrival delay in minutes for each airline. Is this enough data? Since we have a categorical IV and continuous DV should we do an ANOVA? Our DV is normally distributed.

Comment: An ANOVA might be appropriate if you had more than two groups of airlines. An ANOVA _would work_ for only two groups, but software output will be more transparent if you use a two-sample t test.

Answer (score 0):

I think a two-sample t test should work well because your have two groups
and the variable 'avg delay' is normally distributed.

Suppose vector `x1` has delays for 10 airlines in Group 1 and
vector `x2` has delays for 13 airlines in Group 2.
You want to test $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$ against alternative
$H_1: \mu_2 \ne \mu_2$ at the 5% level of significance.

I have used R statistical software to sample some fake data to
use for a demonstration.

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rnorm(10, 3, .5);  x2 = rnorm(13, 5, .6)

summary(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.602   2.560   3.105   2.948   3.317   3.880 
[1] 0.6453066   # sample SD for Gp 1

summary(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.177   4.777   5.191   5.119   5.718   6.305 
[1] 0.9372571   # sample SD for Gp 2

x = c(x1, x2);  gp = rep(1:2, c(10,13))
stripchart(x~gp, ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

[image]

There is no reason to suppose that Group 1 and Group 2 airlines will
have the same variability among airlines in delays, so it is best to
use the Welch 2-sample t test, which does not assume equal variances.

For my (artificial) data, the P-value near 0, indicates that the null
hypothesis should be rejected. That is, the difference between
sample means $\bar X_1 = 2.95$ and $\bar X_2 = 5.12.$ is "statistically
significant." A separate issue is whether about 2 minutes extra delay
in Group2 would be of any practical importance.

```
t.test(x ~ gp)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x by gp
t = -6.5699, df = 20.81, p-value = 1.736e-06
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.858846 -1.483551
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       2.948019        5.119217
```

Most statistical software programs will do a Welch t test, and the
required formulas for computation by hand are given in most basic
statistics texts. Here is output for the same test from a recent
version of Minitab software:

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample   N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       10  2.948  0.645     0.20
2       13  5.119  0.937     0.26

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  -2.171
95% CI for difference:  (-2.860, -1.482)
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
    T-Value = -6.57  P-Value = 0.000  DF = 20
```

In Minitab, I input the sample sizes, means, and standard deviations
rather than the 10 + 13 individual data points. Also, the two programs
round results differently. So answers differ
very slightly between R and Minitab outputs.

*Note:* Following up on my Comment about the possibility (not recommendation) to use an ANOVA, here is the P-value for the one-way ANOVA test `oneway.test` in R, which does not assume equal variances among the
levels of the factor. (I have shown only the P-value here.)

```
oneway.test(x ~ gp)$p.val
[1] 1.735603e-06
```